# Можно ли загружать файлы в транзакции?

Tags: mysql

Обновляю данные порционно данные, используя транзакции в MySQL.

Дальше, в данных есть картинки, которые я выкачиваю.

Можно ли загружать картинки в транзакциях или выкачивать данные стоит между транзакция, а не в них самих, чтобы на долго не блокировать таблицу?

Comment: Зависит от конкретного запроса. Некоторые типы запросов выполняют немедленный и безусловный коммит. Завершая, соответственно, транзакцию вне зависимости от твоего желания.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно понимать. в первую очередь, что такое транзацкия и зачем она вообще нужна. Как минимум это набор операций, объединенных в одну атомарную пачку. Она должна быть как минимум с возможностью отката к исходному состоянию, если что-то пошло не так. И оно должно объединять операции, которые необходимы только для него.

Поэтому если, например, данные обновились в БД, а затем что-то делается с картинками, произошла ошибка и это **критично**, т.к. несоответствует данным в БД - то да, надо заносить в транзакцию. Если операции с картинками ни на что не влияют - то зачем они нужны в транзакции?